# Traefik Redirect from one domain to another

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I´m littlebit struggling about Traefik, I need a redirecton from one domain exapmle1.com/update to another exmaple2.com/test and the paths are also different. I'm using traefik with labels in docker-compose

here are my labels, which was testing:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.sasms.entrypoints=https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.sasms.rule=Host(`example1.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.sasms.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.sasms.tls.certresolver=http"
  - "traefik.http.routers.sasms.service=sasms"
  - "traefik.http.services.sasms.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
  - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
  - "traefik.http.routers.sasms.middlewares=default@file"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.sasms.redirectregex.regex=(.)*"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.sasms.redirectregex.replacement=https://exapmple2.com/test"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.sasms.redirectregex.permanent=false"
```

Thanks in advance